# Como borro un directorio temporal Java

Tags: java

Estoy creando un directorio temporal para guarda unos archivos con:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

 Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("TmpDir");
```

Una vez que finalize la ejecucion de mi programa quiero que se elimine este directorio y todo el contenido dentro. ¿Cual es la forma mas sencilla de eliminar toda la carpeta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes marcar el directorio para que sea borrado al salir de tu app usando [deleteOnExit​()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit--).

> [deleteOnExit​()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit--) Solicita que el archivo o directorio indicado por
> este nombre de ruta abstracto se elimine cuando finalice la máquina
> virtual. Los archivos (o directorios) se eliminan en el orden inverso
> al que se registraron. Invocar este método para eliminar un archivo o
> directorio que ya está registrado para su eliminación no tiene ningún
> efecto. La eliminación se intentará solo para la terminación normal de
> la máquina virtual, según lo definido por la Especificación del
> lenguaje Java.

```
Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("TmpDir");
           
...
...
           
tempDir.toFile().deleteOnExit();
```

También puedes usar el método [delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--)

> [delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--) Elimina el archivo o directorio indicado por este
> nombre de ruta abstracto. Si este nombre de ruta denota un directorio,
> entonces el directorio debe estar vacío para poder eliminarlo. Tenga
> en cuenta que la clase Files define el método de eliminación para
> generar una IOException cuando no se puede eliminar un archivo. Esto
> es útil para informar errores y diagnosticar por qué no se puede
> eliminar un archivo.

En el caso de un directorio es superimportante que previamente te asegures que el directorio no contenga archivos para que se pueda eliminar con exito.

```
Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("TmpDir");
           
...
...
           
 Files.delete(tempDir);
```

---

Puedes usar un método recursivo para eliminar el directorio y su contenido, obtiene la lista de archivos y los elimina, así como al mismo directorio:

```
private void eliminaDirectorio(File dir) {
    for (File file: dir.listFiles()) { //Itera lista de archivos en directorio
        if (file.isDirectory())
            eliminaDirectorio(file);//Elimina directorio
        file.delete();//Elimina archivo.
    }
}
```

Comment: En mi pregunta indique que queria eliminar todo el directorio y su contenido(los archivos), para usar delete() esto  tendria que implementar una funcion  que primero elimine todo el contenido del directorio no?En mi caso me gustaria eliminar toda la carpeta y sus archivos.

Comment: así es, revisa la actualización de mi respuesta. @Serrot

Comment: Como el archivo/carpeta no se borra hasta que termine la ejecución del programa podrías llamar inmediatamente `deleteOnExit`.

Answer (score 0):

Estuve investigando un poco mas y descubri que
Importando:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

Y usando esta linea:

```
 FileUtils.deleteDirectory();
```

De esta manera:

```
    Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("TmpDir");
   /*Operaciones del codigo */
      FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tempDir.toFile());
```

Tambien sirve para borrar un directorio, este borra toda la carpeta con los archivos dentro. Sin necesidad de implementar un método recursivo primero.

Esta es una forma mas directa pero ambos métodos me funcionaron.

Answer (score 0):

```
String tempDirPath = "helloworld";

// Crear el directorio temporal
File tempDir = new File(tempDirPath);
tempDir.mkdir();

// Eliminar el directorio temporal
boolean deleted = tempDir.delete();
if (!deleted) {
    System.out.println("No se pudo eliminar el directorio temporal");
}
```